# Regex to matches a url with or without http in java

Tags: java, regex

I want to validate a url  that is with or without http.
i tried  `^http(s{0,1})://[a-zA-Z0-9_/\\-\\.]+\\.([A-Za-z/]{2,5})[a-zA-Z0-9_/\\&\\?\\=\\-\\.\\~\\%]*`

But this is matches `http://google.com but not www.google.com`.
i want a regex that matches www.google.com too.

Thanks

Comment: use a library if you can: http://commons.apache.org/validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/UrlValidator.html

Comment: If you research using regular expressions to match URLs you'll find that it is very difficult to create one that matches all cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^(?:https?://)? ... the rest of your regex`

- `?:` means do not capture group
- `?` quantifier minification (match if exists, if not - omit it)

P.S. I'm not sure if `quantifier minification` makes sense to english native speakers, this is a rough translation from russian :) Hopefully,  if I'm mistaken, somebody understands what I meant and could fix me.

Answer (score 3):

Try starting your regex with `^(https?://)?` instead of `^http(s{0,1})://`